# Ошибка при загрузке картинок на сайт

Tags: phpmyadmin, php

Ребят, такая проблемка возникла. Хочу сделать загрузку картинок на сайт, пользовался [вот этим ресурсом](http://roothelp.ru/lessons_post.php?id=12), вроде всё поставил правильно, подключил свою базу данных, подключил свою таблицу.

Вот коды моих файлов:

rezultat.php

```
<?php
echo"<a href='add_images_form.php' class='add_images'>
<div class='add_images_text'>ДОБАВИТЬ КАРТИНКУ</div>
</a><br><br>";
include ("bd1.php"); //подключение к базе данных

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT id, img FROM image"); 
// Выбор из базы данных полей id и img

if (!$sql)
{
exit();
}
if (mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0)
{

@$row=mysql_fetch_array($sql);

$i=1;

do
{
echo "<table><tr><td valign='top'>";
echo $i++;
echo "<td>";
echo "<img src='img/$row[img]' class='img'/>";
echo "</td></tr></table><br>";
}
while (@$row = mysql_fetch_array($sql));
}
else
{
echo "<label class='label'>В базе данных нет 
добавленных картинок!</label>";
exit();
}
```

add_images.php:

```
<?php

include ("bd1.php"); //подключение к базе данных

if (isset($_POST['img']))

// Если поле выбора картинки не пустое - закачиваем её на сервер
$maxwidth = "600"; // максимальная ширина картинок на превью
$foto_dir = "img/"; // Директория для фотографий товаров
$foto_name = $fotos_dir.time()."_".basename
($_FILES['myfile']['name']); // Полное имя файла вместе с путем
$foto_light_name = time()."_".basename
($_FILES['myfile']['name']); 
// Имя файла исключая путь
$foto_tag = "<img src=\"$foto_name\" 
border=\"0\">"; // Готовый тэг для вставки картинки на страницу
$foto_tag_preview = "<img src=\"$foto_name\" 
border=\"0\" width=\"$maxwidth\">"; 
// Тот же тэг, но для превью

// Текст ошибок
$error_by_mysql = "<label class=\"label\">
Ошибка при добавлении данных в базу</span>";
$error_by_file = "<label class=\"label\">Невозможно 
загрузить файл в директорию. Возможно её не 
существует</span>";

// Начало
if(isset($_FILES["myfile"]))
{
$myfile = $_FILES["myfile"]["tmp_name"];
$myfile_name = $_FILES["myfile"]["name"];
$myfile_size = $_FILES["myfile"]["size"];
$myfile_type = $_FILES["myfile"]["type"];
$error_flag = $_FILES["myfile"]["error"];

// Если ошибок не было
if($error_flag == 0)
{
$DOCUMENT_ROOT = $_SERVER['DOCMENT_ROOT'];
$upfile = getcwd()."/img/" . time()."_".basename
($_FILES["myfile"]["name"]);
if ($_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'])
{

//Если не удалось загрузить файл

if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['myfile']
['tmp_name'], $upfile))
{
echo "$error_by_file";
exit;
}

}
else
{
echo 'Проблема: возможна атака через загрузку файла. ';
echo $_FILES['myfile']['name'];
exit;
}

$q = "INSERT INTO image (img) VALUES 
('$foto_name')";
$query = mysql_query($q);

// Данные успешно внесены в базу данных, выводим сообщение
if ($query == 'true') {
echo "
<div class='text'>
<p>Картинка успешно добавлена на сервер!</p>
<br><br>
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<a href='add_images_form.php' 
class='add_images'><div class='add_images_text'>
ДОБАВИТЬ ЕЩЕ КАРТИНКУ</div></a>
</td>
<td>
<a href='index.php' class='add_images'>
<div class='add_images_text'>НА ГЛАВНУЮ</div></a>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
";
}

// В противном случае, выводим ошибку при добавлении в базу данных
else {
echo "$error_by_mysql";
}
}
elseif ($myfile_size == 0) {
echo "<br><label class='label'>
Картинка не выбрана!<br><br>
Вернитесь и выберите картинку!</label><br><br>
<a href='add_images_form.php' class='add_images'>
<div class='add_images_text'>ВЫБРАТЬ КАРТИНКУ</div>
</a>";
}
}
?>
```

add_images_form.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<head>
<title> IziKaztka.Ru </title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="icon" href="images/iconweb.png" type="image/x-icon">
<link rel="icon" href="images/iconweb.png" type="image/x-icon">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vhodcss.css">
</head>
<body>
<form name='form' enctype='multipart/form-data' 
method='post' action='add_images.php'>
<p>
<label class='label'>Выберите картинку</label>
<br>
<input type='file' name='myfile' id='myfile' 
class='input'/>
</p>
<br>
<p>
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<input type='image' 
src='images/add_images_save.png' 
title='Сохранить'> /
</td>
<td>
<a href='index.php' class='add_images'>
<div class='add_images_text'>НАЗАД</div></a>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Ошибку выдаёт на 50-й линии файла add_images.php, там написано `['tmp_name'], $upfile))`, и говорит:

> "Невозможно загрузить файл в
> директорию. Возможно её не
> существует".

Помогите разобраться, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Необходимо создать директорию для загружаемых файлов (картинок), и выставить права, разрешающие запись от пользователя, под которым запускается web-сервер (или как вариант дать полные права всем, но это плохо: chmod 0777 ./img/).

Вот у Вас в коде она и настраивается:

```
$foto_dir = "img/"; // Директория для фотографий товаров
```

Comment: А почему плохо разрешать всем? Я именно и хочу, чтобы любой мог загрузить картинку. И не совсем понял, как указать директорию, могли бы по подробней, пожалуйста.

Comment: А всё я разобрался, спасибо большое, просто не спал сутки, теперь крыша на элементарном едет, спасибо ещё раз.